# How to convert the query to a bulk operation?

Tags: mysql, node.js

There is a query:

```
const stmt = "UPDATE `table_name` SET available='yes' WHERE name = ? age = ?";

const params = ['name1', 10]

db_connection.query(stmt, params, (err) => {});
```

Is it possible to convert this query to bulk for the following data?

```
const params = [
        ['name1', 10],
        ['name2', 20],
        ['name2', 30],
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays for that

```
const stmt = "UPDATE `table_name` SET available='yes' WHERE name = ? age = ?";
const params = [
        ['name1', 10],
        ['name2', 20],
        ['name2', 30],
    ]

db_connection.query(stmt, [params], (err) => {});
```